# Defining Table Relations in Web Layer (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, orm

I used to work with relational database (Oracle and mySQL), I define the relationships between tables (constraints) on the database level. In PHP, I noticed the developers define the relationships in the web layer and not in the database. Which method is the best in developing mobile backend (using PHP and mySQL)? Are there any advantages for defining the relationships in the web layer and not in the database?

Thanks

Comment: Your question is quite general. What web layer? What I know is that in the past, and perhaps still, PHP, in combination with MySQL, used the MyISAM Storage Engine. See: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/myisam-storage-engine.html This engine does not support foreign keys, so you have to do this in the web layer. The MyISAM engine might still be preferred because it is sometimes faster and it is easier to work with backups. However, InnoDB is now normally used as the engine.

Comment: Thank you. I understand from your comment that defining the constraints in PHP is used to overcome a limitation in MySQL Storage Engine but it has no advantage over defining the constraints in the Database.